# Use AWK to write a variable to line number 5 after the colon

Tags: awk

I have a file that contains variables that looks like this:

```
Favorite color of John:Blue
Favorite color of Cindy:Red
Favorite color of Greg:Orange
Favorite color of Gary:Red
Favorite color of Patty:White
Favorite color of Meg:Purple
Favorite color of Jason:Pink
```

How would an AWK command be written to change the text after the colon by specifying the line number? I can't base it of character count or fixed space the because the lines vary in length. The colon is a static divider between the object and the variable.

So far I can get the line by doing this:
awk 'NR==5' variables.txt | awk -F":" '{print $2}'
It will even echo the existing variable. But how would I change that text to the word "Green"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two invocations of awk into one:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: 'NR==5 {$2 = "Green"} {print}' variables.txt
```

Note that you need to set both the *input* and *output* field separators: When you assign to a field (`$2 = ...`), then current record (`$0`) gets rewritten using the OFS variable.

Comment: Just found that right when you posted. Haven't yet tested it but I am sure if you are saying the same thing then it is correct. Thank you for not voting down the question. I don't know what I did wrong to get that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Confirmed, worked perfectly, thanks again for the help.